# VBA Test Sql Connection String is Correct w/ Time Out

Tags: sql-server, vba, database-connection, connection-string

Trying to test a connection using the code below which works fine. However, when it encounters a invalid/bad connection string it takes a long time to return the error message that it cannot connect.  This is especially true when trying to connect to a remote server.

Is there a timeout setting or something that I can set to get it to stop trying to connect and return the error message faster?

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cm = New ADODB.Command

    cs =  "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    cn.Open cs

    MsgBox "Connection successful.", vbInformation, "Test Mode Message"

    cn.Close
    Set cm = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Cannot connect”
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`ConnectionTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676718(v=vs.85).aspx) property of your `Connection` instance:

```
cn.ConnectionTimeout = timeoutInSeconds
```